# Cannot Convert 'string' to 'System.DateTime'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having some overloaded method match for some invalid arguments.I'm guessing this is caused by my DateTime value.How do you convert it to string using sqlParemeters?

```
string quo_date = DateTime.Now.ToString();

 quotation1 quotations = new quotation1(quo_product,quo_custname
            ,quo_address,quo_desc,quo_date,quo_printProcess
            ,quo_contact,quo_quantity,quo_size,quo_numberOfPage,quo_cover
            ,quo_inside,quo_ofc,quo_ifc,quo_obc,quo_ibc,quo_onecolor
            ,quo_fullcolor,quo_file);
```

In my class I declared my datetime sqlPrameter into something like this

```
DateTime quo_date
```

Comment: if you declared quo_date as a datetime so change your code from string to :

**DateTime  quo_date = DateTime.Now**

Comment: If it's a `DateTime` it should be a `datetime` in your database too

Comment: @R.You should I use dateTime.now in my Sql **INSERT** method?

Comment: @rainalasa. what s the corresponding column datatype in your database. datetime or varchar?

Comment: @TimSchmelter `command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@quo_date",Quotations.quo_date));` something like this?

Comment: @R.You it is date time.

Comment: @rainalasa, if it is a datetime, so using DateTime.Now will work

Comment: @R.You something like this? `DateTime quo_date = DateTime.Now();`

Comment: DateTime quo_date = DateTime.Now;

Comment: @R.You dude sorry I didn't saw your reply earlier.I figured it out.

Comment: @rainalasa it is ok. Good that you solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer I just change 
this `string quo_date = DateTime.Now.ToString();`

To this `DateTime quo_date = DateTime.Now;`

Comment: Please don't write the answer you have got from anyone else.

Comment: I didn't didn't saw his reply while I'm writting my answer earlier cause I figure it out before I read his comment.sorry.